# Adding functionality to Proto.io html files

Tags: html, wireframe

I have made an prototype on proto.io, and have the html code generated for it by proto.io itself.

Now my question is can I use this HTML code and add functionality like connecting to server and retrieving data?

Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

This is very old, but I ran into the same question and figured out it's not so easy to get clean, usable html & css code from (mockup)tools that auto-generate code. The generated html-code from proto.io will hardly be usable for connecting to a server or similar, because it's full of other code proto.io uses.
Macaw, Webflow and Protoship (in the paid version) seem from my research to be such tools (not tested).